# Can't resize vim splits inside tmux

Tags: vim, putty, tmux

Everything is working fine outside of `tmux`. But in `tmux` I can't resize vim splits with the mouse.
I have `set mouse=a` in my .vimrc. Is there a solution for this?

.tmux.conf:

```
$ cat ~/.tmux.conf
set-option -g mode-mouse on
set-option -g mouse-resize-pane on
set-option -g mouse-select-pane on
set-option -g mouse-select-window on
```

Comment: AFAIK this is a known/unresolved issue. Of course, if you drop your mouse in favor of your keyboard, this becomes pretty much a non-issue.

Comment: Have you tried also setting `ttymouse=xterm2` in *Vim*? That lets me drag around *Vim* splits inside *tmux* (it seems to default to `xterm2` when run with `TERM=xterm`, which is probably the case outside of *tmux*).

Comment: @ChrisJohnsen it works!! please post this comment as an answer and I'll accept it :)

Comment: @romainl Hello! Resizing windows with default vim key bindings is fairly cumbersone IMHO. xD

Comment: This is not a putty issue

Answer (score 76, accepted):

It appears that dragging the status line to resize a split is not possible when the *Vim* option `ttymouse` is `xterm`; it does work when the value is `xterm2` though. The latter value configures Vim to ask for an extended mouse reporting mode that (among other things) provides better dragging support. This extended mode only works with newer versions of *xterm* (and other compatible terminal emulators, including *tmux*), so it is not the default value.

You could use something like the following in your `.vimrc` to set the option:

```
set mouse+=a
if &term =~ '^screen'
    " tmux knows the extended mouse mode
    set ttymouse=xterm2
endif
```

(Though, I am not sure how this will affect actual *screen* instances, which also use a TERM that starts with `screen`.)

When you are outside of *tmux*, the TERM environment variable is probably an `xterm`-ish value, and *Vim* will probe for the *xterm* version by using the `t_RV` control sequence.

Comment: You mention not knowing how this will affect *screen* (as opposed to *tmux*). The answer is: *screen* has the same problem, and this exact fix works there as well.

Comment: the condition does not become true in my Tmux, but simply `set`ting the variable works.

Comment: If you work in a terminal which has over 223 columns, you will need to set `ttymouse` to `sgr` as `xterm2` doesn't go beyond that. You can check if your vim supports `sgr` with `has("mouse_sgr")`. It should always be safe to set `sgr` instead of `xterm2` because it is backwards compatible. See `:help ttymouse`

Answer (score 18):

In my case it resolved both cases: mouse split resize and mouse position problem for wide screen.

[The fix is:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7000960/vim-mouse-problem)

```
if has("mouse_sgr")
    set ttymouse=sgr
else
    set ttymouse=xterm2
end
```

Comment: This worked for me.