# Mouse scrolling in vim through tmux, how to configure?

Tags: vim, putty, tmux, scrolling

I'm using a combination of PuTTY, tmux and vim. If I just open an SSH connection with PuTTY and then open vim, mouse scrolling works as expected. But if I open tmux and then open vim inside tmux the scrolling only partially works, meaning I can scroll downwards as usual but I'm unable to scroll upwards. If I scroll upwards the buffer just jerks "up and down" and just stays in the same spot. "set -g mode-mouse on" doesn't seem to make a difference (I do reload the conf afterwards with "tmux source-file ~/.tmux.conf"), works the same way either way.

Edit: I also noticed that scrolling works like expected in tmux in terminal but not in vim. Only options related to mouse/terminal I have in vim is "set mouse=a" and "set t_Co=256".

Any ideas?

Comment: The following link contains the solution:
http://superuser.com/questions/549930/cant-resize-vim-splits-inside-tmux

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Summary

The issue clearly starts with PuTTY, but it doesn't necessarily stop there. There is a link to a potential fix for the PuTTY issue below, as well as an analysis of the issue as a whole.

---

## Issue Description

### Configuration

`vim` with `mouse=a` enabled for scrolling, selection, and cursor movement

`tmux`, with no `tmux` mouse functionality enabled, i.e. the following:

```
set -g mode-mouse off
set -g mouse-select-pane off
set -g mouse-resize-pane off
set -g mouse-select-window off
```

### Use Case

A typical use case is to use `vim` **inside** of `tmux`. Avoiding negative interactions between `tmux` and `vim` is one of the primary reasons to disable `tmux` scrolling.

### Behavior

Please note that the following only occurs when using PuTTY as the terminal emulator, and is not reproducible in gnome-terminal or any other tested Linux terminal emulator.

When attempting to 'scroll up' using the mouse in `vim` **inside** of a `tmux` session, the action simply fails. As OP describes, it is often possible to see the buffer jerking 'up and down' as if there is a counter-action taking place with each scroll attempt (more on this below).

This is basically the same as OP's description, but recapped just in case something isn't clear in my explanation or OP's question.

---

## Potential Solution -- PuTTY

There appears to be an issue where PuTTY sends an extraneous ScrollDown event with every ScrollDown/ScrollUp event. This means that each attempt to scroll up gets cancelled out and nothing happens. Conversely, when scrolling down, each scroll event is doubled. The behavior is easy to validate by looking at the `vim` scrolling behavior *first outside* of `tmux` (where scrolling works properly), and *second inside* of `tmux` (where scrolling up does not work, and a single attempt to scroll down scrolls twice as much).

*According to the following gmane thread*, the issue described above is resolved with a patch from Putty-X (https://github.com/atsepkov/putty-X/commit/bbcedf5a85ca1ccaa27005e7f7ebeb4c8a783b88):

**Link to gmane thread**: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.terminal-emulators.tmux.user/5498.

**NOTE:** I haven't validated the above solution myself, so please review the gmane thread for additional information.

---

## Additional Observations

Where it ***really*** gets interesting is that this is a new issue not reproducible using older versions of `tmux`/`vim`. Using the same version of PuTTY (0.63), the issue can be actively demonstrated on an Ubuntu 13.10 system, while an Ubuntu 12.04 system does not exhibit the issue.

At first, the issue seems to point to a system configuration delta (i.e. missing ncurses-term or similar), but no fix has been identified using this type of solution. Furthermore, the multiple reports of this same issue (including this thread) tend to support the existence of the issue.

Because of the co-dependent nature of the issue and versions of the related software, it seems the issue isn't limited to a single application. It may be that a newer version of `tmux`/`vim` 'fixed' something that created a regression. Or, it may be that a newer version of `tmux`/`vim` simply exposed the existing issue in PuTTY. Either way, it will require some additional investigation to fully iron out. Please find some pertinent version information below if this can help anyone in their investigation.

---

## Version Information

**Ubuntu 12.04** version info ('scrolling up' in `vim` inside of `tmux` **works**):

- `tmux`: 1.6-1
- `vim`: 7.3.429-2

**Ubuntu 13.10** version info ('scrolling up' in `vim` inside of `tmux` is **broken**):

- `tmux`: 1.8-4
- `vim`: 7.4.000-1

Also of note -- the gmane poster reported not observing the issue on `tmux` 1.7 + `vim` 7.3. Poster's first observation of the issue was also with `tmux` 1.8 + `vim` 7.4.

---

Hopefully, at the very least, this answer provides anyone dedicated to (or stuck with) PuTTY an option for working around this issue. Beyond that, hopefully someone can make sense of the additional observations above and help bring the topic to a proper resolution.

Comment: Disabling "bind-key a send-prefix" without disabling the mouse worked for me... Does vim use tmux style sessions?

Comment: @Andreas, thanks for the suggestion. I've tried it with no luck (issue appears with or without config modification). What tmux+vim version combination(s) are you using? What does the `.tmux.conf` look like before and after you've disabled `bind-key a send-prefix`?

Answer (score 5):

I have no problem with an ubuntu 16.04 installation. tmux is the default apt-get installed version. Vim is version 8. PuTTY is version 0.67

Both scrolling and clicking works inside vim when hosted in a tmux session.

~/.tmux.conf

```
set-option -g mouse on
```

Be aware that the tmux options for mouse control have changed from earlier versions.

~/.vimrc

```
set mouse=a
```

Be aware that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27909249/158483) suggests that a vim plugin could be the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone that ends up here: this has been fixed in the 0.64 pre-release, which you can download from the official PuTTY website.

Comment: Updating putty fixed this issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is the only way that I have been able to get scrolling to work properly:

Put:

```
set -g terminal-overrides 'xterm*:smcup@:rmcup@'
```

In the file: `~/.tmux.conf`

Comment: This does not work with multiple panes.